# unable to populate redux store on android

Tags: android, react-native, redux

For some obscure reason, my app works perfectly fine on iOS but on Android, none of my dispatch actions are populating my redux store. The state stays empty, however, it has worked once without me doing anything, but stopped working again.

Here is an exemple of how I call my action

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()

dispatch({
            type: 'SET_TOKEN',
            payload: data
          });
```

and my reducer

```
import React, { useReducer, createContext } from "react";

const initState = {
  token: null
};

const AuthReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_TOKEN':
      console.log('SET_TOKEN', action)
      return {
        ...state,
        token: action.payload.access_token
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default AuthReducer
```

```
const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    {},
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))
  );

return(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <LocalizationProvider>
        <StatusBar
          barStyle="dark-content"
        />
        {!netInfo &&
          <View style={styles.networkAlertContainer}>
            <View style={styles.networkAlert}>
              <Icon name='wifi-off' color='white' size={18}/>
              <Margin size={0.5}/>
              <Text size={'medium_bold'} color={Colors.WHITE}>
                {t(trans['error.no_network'])}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        }
        <Navigator />
      </LocalizationProvider>
    </Provider>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error , you can share the code of you "store" ?
You have a Provider in the root of the App?

```
  return (
<Provider store={store}>
  <AppRouter />
</Provider> );
```

And my store is this and working

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
    movies: moviesReducer, });
export const store = createStore( reducers , compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof reducers>;
```